# How do I automatically open and login to several web sites

Tags: asp.net, http

I manage several web sites for customers, (Umbraco and Wordpress) its taking me forever to switch between them to keep them updated, now im determined to do something about this. Im making a small web application where i have a link to the sites i manage and then open them in a iframe in the center of mi application. But how do i automatically log into the web site, so i dont have to input this information each time?

Answer (score 0):

you need to use [cookies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178194.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Login credentials are generally stored on the client side in cookies, so your web application cannot handle this unless it were to proxy cookie information.

Try using a browser that allows you store login information, like Firefox. That's what I use, and I manage about 10 Wordpress sites.